# How to pass a custom array of data to a shader

Tags: unity, textures, shaders

I want to know how to pass an array of data (it will be an encoded map, actually) to the fragment shader so I can query it as an array.

AFAIK this is sadly not implemented in unity, so I'm looking for a nice workaround.

I've thought on using a texture but I don't really know how to query the data without running into precision errors (i.e. query a single texture pixel as if it were an array). It is actually really important that it never fails because of precision, and I rather not rely on the internal floating point implementation.

Comment: As far as I know rectangle samplers uses non-normalized UVs, meaning you enter UVs in texel coordinates if that is what are you looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by rectangle sampler? The only thing I really know is the sampler2d and that uses coordinates from 0.0 to 1.0 (in float). How would I go into using a rectangle sampler?

Comment: There are many kinds of samplers, check [official site](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL))

Comment: Ok, so it appears that I need to use an isampler2d instead of a normal sampler2d. I assumed I could just replace the type and it would work out of the box, but it doesn't seem to work under unity :S

Comment: To be honest, I never implemented this (so I might be wrong). As I understand it, one need to create rectangle texture and sample it with rectangle sampler - the prefix is only sampler in/output type. (float vec vs int vec)

Comment: I don't know about Unity, but if you want to perfectly access texels in your texture, you just have to ensure your textures are sized to powers of two (floats are exact when representing sums of powers of two); and use nearest neighbor interpolation.

Comment: I'm already forced to use powers of two sizez textures because of unity, and you're right into that, didn't think about it.